# En que estoy mal?

Tags: html

![introducir la descripción de la im(https://i.stack.imgur.com/er4eU.jpg)

Comment: Te recomiendo leer la documentación sobre como preguntar.

Comment: Puedes leer esta sección https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y luego editar tu pregunta para que haya mas posibilidades que tu pregunta sea aceptada

Comment: No puedo ver el código de tu fotografía. De todas maneras esta es una página sobre código, no sobre fotografía ¿Por qué poner fotografías en lugar de código? ¡es más complicado! y no se puede copiapegar el código de una fotografía ni hacer búsquedas de texto; por favor: **PON EL CÓDIGO**, **NO FOTOGRAFÍAS**.

Answer (score 1):

Esta mal toda tu sintaxis.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function calcula_triangulo_equilatero(){
  let base = document.getElementById('base').value;
  let altura = document.getElementById('altura').value;
  let area = (base * altura)/2;
  let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  resultado.innerHTML = "El area es: "+area;
  
}
```

```html
<input id="base" type="number" placeholder="introduce la base">
<input id="altura" type="number" placeholder="introduce la altura">
<br><br>

<button onclick="calcula_triangulo_equilatero()">
Calcula area
</button>
<br><br>
<div id="resultado">

</div>
```

En mi ejemplo separe todo el script en un solo lado y el html de otro.